# MySQL select rows with date like

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, date-formatting

In MySQL I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, descr FROM book ORDER BY date
```

Date is in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

I want to select only the the books from *January 2012*. I have tried to use `like` but that does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"Date is in format yyyy-mm-dd"* - Is the date column an actual date value?  Or just a string?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, descr FROM book 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %m') = DATE_FORMAT('2012-01-01', '%Y %m')
ORDER BY date
```

Or using [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, descr FROM book 
WHERE Month(date) = Month('2012-01-01')
AND Year(date) = Year('2012-01-01')
ORDER BY date;
```

Or using [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) functions

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, descr FROM book 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-01-01'
AND '2012-01-31'
ORDER BY date;
```

Or using [`<=`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than-or-equal) and [`>=`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than-or-equal) operators

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, descr FROM book 
WHERE date >= '2012-01-01'
AND date <= '2012-01-31'
ORDER BY date;
```

#### [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa4a4/1)

Comment: Thnx for the info this helps alot!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `>=` and `<=` operators here. Check the below code:

```
SELECT *
FROM book
WHERE date >= '2012-01-01' AND date <= '2012-01-31'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using like also works. With @hims056 fiddle, you can test it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, date FROM book 
WHERE date LIKE '2012-01%'
ORDER BY date;
```

However, it's not usual to use a like for date filtering, for me it's more natural to use >= and <= , or between. Also, there's a performance benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, descr FROM book WHERE YEAR(date) = '2012' and MONTH(date) = '1'
```

This works if your "date"-column is a MySQL date field.

Answer (score 4):

If you are adamant that you want to use the LIKE syntax, you can convert the date to CHAR first:

SELECT DISTINCT date, descr FROM book WHERE CAST(date AS char) LIKE '2012-01%' ORDER BY date;

Comment: This is handy to find a specific time, independent of the year, such as `LIKE '%-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: WHERE date LIKE '2012-01%' works fine but using CAST is nice cause no warnings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, descr
FROM book
WHERE YEAR = DATE(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = '1'
```

This will give you this years books

Comment: You will need to correct that to `WHERE YEAR(date) >= DATE(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = '1'` to make it work and it will be **VERY** inefficient query calling 3 functions for **each** row