# How to select from a given month without using between or >=?

Tags: mysql, date, select, between

I have an array of all months in strings ie ['January', 'February',...etc].  I want to loop over this array and pass it to a SQL command that will get everything within that month. 
For example

```
SELECT * WHERE foodate='January'
```

will return all records from January 1st to January 31st.

Comment: What datatype is the foodate column?

Comment: which year should it use? the current one?

Comment: the column is datetime.  the year may vary but to keep it simple for now just the current year.

Comment: The MySQL manual is your friend http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
select *from your_table where monthname(foodate)='January' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that foodate is varchar or date type?

If it's varchar you can do something like :

```
SELECT * WHERE foodate LIKE '%January%'
```

Or you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216033/mysql-select-rows-with-date-like) some response for date type

Comment: foodate is a Datetime field