# PHP and MYSQLI with LIKE array: does not echo all content correctly

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have come this far and seem to be stuck on this trivial output issue, apologies in advance.

The $getexhibitions is an array and works when only this aspect of code is running. I have then added $results based on a LIKE keyword link that is intended to be an array within the array.

My problem is that the output is supposed to show $getexhibitions->title  with the list of each $results->sponsor underneath. Java then creates a drop down with specific sponsor information. This will then repeat for the preceeding 8 years as so.

As you can see the code is getting stuck and i feel as though this may be a div or { problem or it may be more with the array code. Thanks in advance.

http://tenmoregirls.com/tenmoregirls/sponsors.php

```
    <?php
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 

$query_getexhibitions = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM exhibitions ORDER BY year DESC");
if ($query_getexhibitions) { 
    while($getexhibitions = $query_getexhibitions->fetch_object())        {

            echo "<a>$getexhibitions->year | $getexhibitions->title</a>", "<br />";

$sponsorlink = $getexhibitions->year;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM sponsors WHERE (`year` LIKE '%".$sponsorlink."%')");  
if ($result) {   
      while($results = $result->fetch_object()) {

                   echo "<a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"subheading\" onclick = \"document.getElementById($results->id).style.display='block'\" >$results->sponsor</a>", "<br />";

           echo "<div id=\"$results->id\" style=\"display: none;\">
           <a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" onclick = \"document.getElementById($results->id).style.display='none'\"><img src=\"exhibitstyles/links/close.png\" alt=\"close\" width=\"20\"/></a><br />";        
        echo '<img src="sponsorimages/'.$results->logo.'">';
        echo $results->summary, "<br />";
                    echo "<a href=\"http://$results->website\" target=\"_blank\">$results->website</a>", "<br /><br /><br />";

} "</div>"; } "</div>";
}}   exit(); ?>
```

Comment: Echoing HTML in PHP is **bad** idea again :(

Comment: I realise, my code is otherwise short and simple! Any help?

Comment: Please tell where divs give problem ? This is too much code.

Comment: Read up on how to do `LIKE` with date columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216033/mysql-select-rows-with-date-like

Comment: if you click my website link you will see: the array is not outputting in full and list items are getting stuck under other sections

Comment: @Mave, my like method is working well through other pages, i do not understand what should be changed if that aspect works?

Comment: whereever you want to put html simply do like this 
`?>
<html code>
<?php`

Comment: will that solve the array? it will take me time to test this...ill be back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a problem with PHP and MYSQLI, but just with a wrong closing div tag, which is outside the loop. There is also one additional closing tag that don't seem to refer to anything. Try to move `</div>` tag inside the loop and delete the other one.

Edit:
You were also missing `echo` command before `"</div>";` tag, because you used `;` on the end of the previous line. <s>You also can't use `,` between multiple echo parameters. `.` is a concatenation operator for strings in php.</s> Whereas `.` is a concatenation operator for strings, echo construction also allows the usage of `,` between arguments. My bad.

Try this:

```
while($getexhibitions = $query_getexhibitions->fetch_object())        {

    echo "<a>$getexhibitions->year | $getexhibitions->title</a><br />";

    $sponsorlink = $getexhibitions->year;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM sponsors WHERE (`year` LIKE '%".$sponsorlink."%')");  
    if ($result) {   
        while($results = $result->fetch_object()) {
            echo "<a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"subheading\" onclick = \"document.getElementById($results->id).style.display='block'\" >$results->sponsor</a><br />";

            echo "<div id=\"$results->id\" style=\"display: none;\">
                <a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" onclick = \"document.getElementById($results->id).style.display='none'\"><img src=\"exhibitstyles/links/close.png\" alt=\"close\" width=\"20\"/></a><br />";        
            echo '<img src="sponsorimages/'.$results->logo.'">';
            echo $results->summary . "<br />";
            echo "<a href=\"http://$results->website\" target=\"_blank\">$results->website</a><br /><br /><br />";
            echo "</div>";
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i had started that way to no avail and have tried multiple variations since, it is within the loop nd the second div deleted with no difference...weird...

Comment: There may be an error in your javascript code then.

Comment: thats an venue i had not yet taken, all arrays work independently its only putting them together...is there a trick to closing a tag within a java line?

Comment: Honestly, i don't think it was a javascript issue, but rather wrong php syntax. I suggested js error because i though there is an external code with js logic, but then i realised it's just simply here. However, there may be also javascript errors if you use numbers as ids.

Comment: i think we came up with the solution at the same time! i did not realise the ',' issue so will change that everywhere and not echoing the div has caused problems for so long and now i know why! i just found the id java issue after fixing the div....thankyou for your patience and thught, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry for disguiding you, I just found that using `,` in echo construction is also correct, which I didn't know before.

Comment: no worries! I wont change it then...really appreciate your help...i have all my pages working now inclusive of custom back end! just down to frustrating css!