# Laravel 5: Query Builder: Get the record using date in datetime datatype

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have column date and the data type is datetime, now I want to fetch all the related date with a certain date.

I want to monitor how many items I've bought in a certain year but what I have right now is, I'm not getting any value.

**Example**

My date is:

```
$date['start_date'] = "2019-01-01";
$date['end_date']   = "2019-12-31";
```

I have 3 records

```
1) 
   name: Laptop
   date(date bought): 2018-03-05 14:23:00
2) 
   name: Shoes
   date(date bought): 2019-03-05 23:05:00
3) 
   name: Bag
   date(date bought): 2019-10-05 18:35:00
```

**Model**

```
return DB::table('x')
      ->whereBetween('date', [date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date['start_date'])), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date['end_date']))])
->get()->toArray();
```

Question: Is my query wrong?

Comment: plz post the `$date['start_date']` and `$date['end_date']`

Comment: Updated my post,

Comment: You forgot `->get()` mehod

Comment: Updated again my post.

Comment: Your code is fine. Can you `dd()`?

Comment: the `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date['start_date']))` is as same as `$date['start_date']`.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include the time,

Comment: so r u sure about there are datas between those date?

Comment: Yes, i have data on those date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent)

Comment: The problem is likely that your `date` column is `datetime` or similar (your sample records include time) but your `whereBetween()` is using only dates.  Check the answers in the duplicate for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` as you would in normal SQL and treat the datetime field as you would a text field

```
 return DB::table('x')->where('date', 'like', "2019-%")->get()->toArray();
```

or even better with your Model

```
 return YourModelX::where('date', 'like', "2019-%")->get()->toArray();
```

or you use whereBetween with the format of your cells in the database:

```
// datetime
return YourModelX::whereBetween('date', ['2019-01-01 00:00:00','2019-12-31 23:59:59'])->get();
// date
return YourModelX::whereBetween('date', ['2019-01-01','2019-12-31'])->get();
```

Comment: no, because it's not a handled as a datetime but like a string

Comment: Example if I bought items in 2018, It will not show? because it is only 2019-%? because I have filtered for this, the user will choose what year/month/day

Comment: MySQL has functions working with dates, you shouldn't be treating them as text - performance alone will be much worse.  That goes double for using `LIKE`, unless you have a carefully constructed index.  In the given example, [MySQL's `YEAR()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216091/6089612) function would make much more sense, and the corresponding [`whereYear()` in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).  This is all moot since that query doesn't help OP anyway, but wanted to point out this is not a good approach.